# Is this proof that $e^z$ is transcendental correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, transcendental-functions

*Lemma*.  If $p(z)$ is a non-zero polynomial and $k\geq 1$ a natural number, then there exists a polynomial $q(z)$ of the same degree such that $\frac{d}{dz}\Big(p(z)\cdot e^{kz}\Big) = q(z)\cdot e^{kz}$.  (Indeed,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dz}\Big(p(z)\cdot e^{kz}\Big) &= p'(z)\cdot e^{kz} + kp(z)\cdot e^{kz} \\
&= e^{kz}\Big(p'(z) + kp(z)\Big),
\end{align}
and $p'(z) + kp(z)$ has the same degree as $p(z)$.)$\quad\square$

Recall that $f(z)$ is an *algebraic function* iff there exists a polynomial $F(z, y)\in\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]$ such that $F(z, f(z))\equiv 0.$

Assume that $e^z$ is algebraic and let
\begin{equation}
F(z, y) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k(z)y^k = p_0(z) + \sum_{k=1}^n p_k(z)y^k,\quad p_n(z)\not\equiv 0,
\end{equation}

be a polynomial of minimal degree in $y$ such that $F(z, e^z) \equiv 0$.

Now, $p_0(z)$ cannot be the zero polynomial, or else $F(z, y) = y\cdot G(z, y)$, where $G$ is a polynomial of strictly lesser degree in $y$ than $F$ such that $G(z, e^z)\equiv 0$ (this because $e^z$ vanishes nowhere), contradicting the minimality of $deg_y(F)$.  So call $d:= deg(p_0\big(z)\big)$ and take $\frac{d^{d+1}}{dz^{d+1}}$ of both sides of the equation $F(z, e^z) \equiv 0$.  By linearity of derivative, the lemma, and the fact that the $(d+1)^{th}$ derivative of a degree $d$ polynomial is identically zero, this results in the equation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n q_k(z)e^{kz} \equiv 0,
\end{equation}
where $\deg(q_k) = \deg(p_k)$ for all $k\geq 1$.  We may factor $e^z$ out of this equation to obtain
\begin{equation}
e^z\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q_{k+1}(z)e^{kz} \equiv 0,
\end{equation}
and since $e^z$ vanishes nowhere this equality implies that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q_{k+1}(z)e^{kz} \equiv 0.
\end{equation}

But this implies that $\deg_y(F)$ was not minimal after all, contradiction.  So $e^z$ must be transcendental, *ce qu'il fallait démontrer*.  $\clubsuit$

Comment: this looks right to me

Comment: Isn't it much easier to use that the repeated (complex) derivate of a polynomial eventually ends in the zero-function whereas the derivate of $e^z$ keeps $e^z$ forever ?

Comment: @Peter Where does this come into play, given that we are dealing with *products* of these functions, whose behaviour under derivatives is less straightforward?

Still, I think I indirectly use the facts you suggest in (1) the lemma and (2) the end of the proof.  Indeed, the whole proof hinges on the fact that the $y$-degree 0 term, being a polynomial, will vanish under repeated derivatives while the other terms cannot.

Comment: @Peter: the OP is trying to prove that $e^x$ is not *algebraic*. This is a much stronger condition than proving that $e^x$ is not a polynomial, which is what your argument would show. With a little additional effort your argument would also show that $e^x$ is not rational, but algebraic functions are an even wider class of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine, although note that

- you never use this fact that $q(z)$ has the same degree as $p(z)$ so you don't need to mention it, and
- your definition of an algebraic function is slightly incorrect: $F$ should live in $\mathbb{C}[z, y]$. Fortunately this doesn't affect your argument, which proves that $e^z$ is not algebraic in this stronger sense. (**Edit:** this is not the definition used by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) or [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicFunction.html), although it is used by [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/algebraicfunction). Personally I think Wikipedia and MathWorld are just wrong here. The Wikipedia article makes no use of the hypothesis that the coefficients are required to be in $\mathbb{Q}$ and everything it has to say applies to algebraic functions over $\mathbb{C}$. I suppose one can just specify the ground field but I still personally think "algebraic function," with no qualifications, should mean over $\mathbb{C}$.)

For fun, here is an alternative argument. We will just directly show that if $F$ is a nonzero polynomial then $F(z, e^z)$ is not identically zero. Suppose the monomial of largest degree that occurs in $F$ is $z^n e^{mz}$ (where largest is with respect to the lexicographic order where $m$ takes precedence over $n$; that is, we first consider the terms with $m$ maximal, then among those take the term with $n$ maximal). Then

$$\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{F(z, e^z)}{z^n e^{mz}} \neq 0$$

(it must equal the coefficient of $z^n e^{mz}$ because $z^n e^{mz}$ dominates all other terms), so $F(z, e^z) \neq 0$. Here the limit to $\infty$ should be understood as happening along the positive real axis. However, this argument really requires that we're working over a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, whereas the differentiation argument works over any field of characteristic zero.

Comment: Other arguments are possible; for example you could look carefully at the Taylor series expansion of $F(z, e^z)$, or show that any nonconstant algebraic function has either a zero or a singularity or both (and $e^z$ has neither). At least I think that's true, although I'm not sure how to write down a clean proof.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

However, I have a few questions about the two bullet points (will address the rest of the post in other comments).

(1) "You never use this fact ..." It's true that we could weaken the lemma, but we do need something that assures that the $p_k(z)$ do not vanish with repeated derivation and don't yield $e^{mz}$ terms for $m > k$.
(2) "Your definition ..." Are you sure?  For example, is $\pi z$ an algebraic function?  Not if we require $f(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for algebraic $f$.

Comment: I must say that your simple proof is quite elegant.  I'd like to try the other two approaches you suggest as well ... the Taylor series approach seems difficult, though, because unless I'm overlooking something obvious you'd need to expand and then prove that no suitable coefficient double sequence yields simultaneous zeros to a finite number of equations determined by the expansion ... right?  But I'm sure there's a better way (just don't ask how I know -- I say this only from a sense of intuitive pessimism about my problem-solving acumen ;) )

Comment: @Dave: 1) you only need that the derivative has the form $q(z) e^{kz}$ and is nonzero, but it's clearly nonzero since the function you're differentiating is not a constant. 2) Well, this is annoying. Wikipedia and MathWorld both agree with you, but I think this is just wrong (and PlanetMath agrees with me). Nobody thinks of $\pi z$ as a transcendental function. When people say that $e^z$ is transcendental they mean it's transcendental over $\mathbb{C}[z]$.

Comment: And the Taylor series argument is straightforward, you just look at the fastest growing term again. I can edit it in if you'd like to see the details.